# Слайдер с переключателями в виде слайдов

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, анимация, slider

Можете подсказать слайдер, при помощи которого можно было бы добиться подобного? Не хотелось бы писать такое с 0.
Основная фишка, в том, что левый и правый слайдер являются одновременно переключателями prev и next соотвецтвенно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите `slick slider`

Comment: Читал документацю. Не нашел подобного функционала в нем.

Comment: Какого именно функционала вы не нашли?

Comment: Превью-переключателей. Тобеж там нельзя устанавливать на кнопки prev и next изображения предыдущего и следующего слайда, соотвецтвенно. К тому же, необходима плавная анимация при переходе слайдов между prev active и next состояниями.

Comment: @Spartak я в `slick slider` есть вариант `Slider Syncing` я думаю он вам как раз и подходит

Comment: Чем вас `Center Mode` не устраивает? И анимация вроде бы там есть http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Да, вы правы. Center Mode - это то, что нужно. Я был не внимателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: slick slider c параметром Center Mode. Спасибо Stepan-у Kasyanenko.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/308507)

Comment: @AK это единственный ответ. топикастер скопировал его из комментария.